# PHP MySQL combine tables question, reading the fetch

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I made a query that is joining the same table - users- twice,
with JOINs.

```
SELECT  * from tbl1 
  JOIN  tbl2 ON tbl2.USER_ID = tbl1.ID 
  JOIN  tbl2 as alias ON tbl1.ID = tbl2.TEACHER_ID 
 WHERE  tbl1.ID = 45
```

The first call to that table is regular, and the second time I use an alias using AS.
When I get the result in phpMyAdmin, I see the results are not referred to as the alias, but with the usual name, that's like this:

USERNAME => Ted, ID_NUMBER=>33322552, ... ,USERNAME=>Josh ....

How can I read that associative array

Comment: Please provide more information on the table schema. How you connect to mysql, and the PHP code responsible for that

Comment: SELECT * from tbl1 JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.USER_ID = tbl1.ID JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.ID = tbl2.TEACHER_ID WHERE tbl1.ID = 45

Comment: Update your question with the SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this query, you are not using an alias, you are refering to a real table called tbl2, twice. This will not work.

```
SELECT * from tbl1 
JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.USER_ID = tbl1.ID 
JOIN tbl2 as alias ON tbl1.ID = tbl2.TEACHER_ID   
//                              ^^^^ there's no alias here, it's still tbl2 
WHERE tbl1.ID = 45
```

Rewrite it to:

```
SELECT * from tbl1 
JOIN tbl2 AS t2A ON t2A.USER_ID = tbl1.ID 
JOIN tbl2 AS t2B ON tbl1.ID = T2B.TEACHER_ID 
WHERE tbl1.ID = 45
```

The `as` keyword is optional.
This way there can be no misunderstanding which version of tbl2 you are refering to.

**The difference between the two queries**

Note that you can also rewrite query 2 as:

```
SELECT * from tbl1 
JOIN tbl2 ON (tbl2.USER_ID = tbl1.ID) OR (tbl2.teacher_ID = tbl1.id)  
WHERE tbl1.ID = 45
```

In that case you would rewrite query 1 as:

```
SELECT * from tbl1 
JOIN tbl2 ON (tbl2.USER_ID = tbl1.ID) AND (tbl2.teacher_ID = tbl1.id)  
WHERE tbl1.ID = 45
```

See the difference?